# Tool for comparing two databases and creating ALTER scripts to sync them

Tags: sql, schema, ibm-data-studio

I have two IBM DB2 databases A and B with different database schemas. Database A schema is older, and database B schema is newer. I would neet to create SQL alter scripts that can update A schema to match that of B schema. This can ofcourse be done manually, but is there a tool that could analyse the two databases and do this for me?

I am using the free IBM Data Studio client for querying the database. Can the above operation be done using this tool?

Comment: liquibase http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html

Answer (score 0):

Redgate sql compare is one of tge bests.

Comment: Bear in mind that this question is about IBM, and Red Gate has comparison tools for SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.